# User Import: Possible to use other variables in the user notification email?

Tags: users, tokens

We are using the User Import module to populate the User list, and having it send out a notification email with a temporary login URL. In the notification email section of User Import configuration, it is stated:

*Customize the body of the welcome e-mail, which is sent to imported members. Available variables are: !username, !site, !password, !uri, !uri_brief, !mailto, !login_uri, !edit_uri, !login_url.*

In this site we have some custom fields added to User which are being populated via User Import of .csv files. We would like to include a variable in the message body that picks up a numerical value from those fields. There is a set of fields of the name pattern "field_schools_owned_zone_1" which goes from 1 to 6; then in a View we have a math field that sums up those 6 field values for each user. It is that sum that we want to use.

Can this email form accept variables other than those listed? If so, how can we determine the replacement string for that math field value so it can work in the email message?

--Thanks--

Answer (score 0):

Probably not easily an existing request in the issue queues shows people want to add fields from the Content Profile module on the 6.x branch of this module:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1060394

There is a small patch in that issue that adds custom profile fields into the allowed list. The tokens would be in the same format as the given `!username` examples, eg `!field_schools_owned_zone_1` for 1 of your fields.

Until that patch is added to the version of the module you're using you'd have to apply or adapt that patch to your site.